# How to compare the values of two resultset in java

Tags: java, resultset

I have two tables. And these tables have the same schema consisting of userid, username. I want to check is there any common `username` in `table1` and `table2`.

```
 rs1 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table1")
 rs2 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table2")
```

My logic is:

- `while(rs1.next())`
- compare the value of `rs1` with every value of `rs2`.
- `If` there match found print one of the value `else` print both the values.

Is there a way to achieve this in  java... Please anyone help me ... Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a single SQL statement:

```
select table1.username from table1, table2 where table1.username = table2.username
```

This will only return usernames that appear in both tables, so no post-processing will be needed.

This construct is called an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join). If you also want to identify usernames that are unique to `table1` and/or `table2`, you could use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins).

Answer (score 1):

You can either solve it through SQL statement IN and NOT IN or you can try something like this:

```
public boolean compareResultSets(ResultSet resultSet1, ResultSet resultSet2) throws SQLException{
        while (resultSet1.next()) {
            resultSet2.next();
            ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet1.getMetaData();
            int count = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                if (!resultSet1.getObject(i).equals(resultSet2.getObject(i))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-Code:

```
if ( A.type = B.type )
{
    PRINT same type

    if ( A.format = B.format )
    {
        PRINT same format

        if ( A.value = B.value )
        {
            PRINT same value
        }
        else
        {
            PRINT different value
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PRINT different format
    }
}
else
{
    PRINT different type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example to solve this:

```
rs1 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table1")
rs2 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table2")

while(rs1.next()) {
// Compare till rs1 reachs its last record.
  while(rs2.next()) {
     if() {
       // Do your code here...
     }
  }

// this will move resultSet cursor to the first position.
rs2.first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:-

```
String query = "(" + query1 +") intersect ("+ query2 + ")";
```

Where in the intersect operation will anyway give you the common columns.

P.S. :- I know this question is old, but it might help somebody.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is already given by Akash5288 and Edited by Pavel Smirnov. And this worked for me like magic. I don't have access to Like or Comment on the original answer, that's why I am re-posting it. Thanks a lot. Just one edit from my side: **rs2.beforeFirst();** will work better than **rs2.first();**.

I am giving an example to solve this:

```
rs1 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table1")
rs2 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table2")

while(rs1.next()) {
// Compare till rs1 reachs its last record.
  while(rs2.next()) {
     if() {
       // Do your code here...
     }
  }

// this will move resultSet cursor to the first position.
rs2.first();
}
```